# What is this material using between metal joints? using for cars

Tags: seal

I'm looking at this material using between metal ... Used for cars,
what is it and what is it called?

[image]

Comment: It’s a gap sealer , easy to purchase...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! There was a close flag put on your question because you asked a shopping question. I've removed the "offending" portion of it, so now the question should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, its called seam sealer

Comment: I told you that in the comment above, gap sealer...